# Gatsby Develop renders perfectly without errors. Gatsby Build renders incorrectly with errors on generated site

Tags: gatsby

When I run `gatsby develop`, it generates my site correctly without any errors in my terminal or browser console. When I run `gatsby build`, however, the terminal shows no errors but the browser console contains an error and the statically generated site doesn't display my content correctly.

This is the error that I am seeing in my browser on `gatsby build`:

```
history.js:90 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'replace' on 'Location': '//' is not a valid URL.
    at navigate (https://ianholden.co.uk/app-ce9755a68972af53fb20.js:1:7755)
```

I can not see where this issue stems from. I have tried `gatsby clean` and I have checked all internal links via the `<Link>` component have a legitimate `to` attribute.

I am using GraphQL to pull in data from a local WordPress GraphQL endpoint.